# How do I combine two content types in one Views block and get them to sort correctly?

Tags: views

On my site, I have content types for Tradeshows and Webinars. I would like to have a block that shows the next 5 upcoming events by date, coming from either content type. I have Views set up to retrieve items from both types, and have the sort criteria set up with the date field from each type (they are different fields), in ascending order.  Ie., the Sort Criteria section looks like: Webinar Date (asc), Tradeshow Date (asc).

If I set the Views pager to display all items, I see a list of all the tradeshows, followed by the webinars.  It looks like Views retrieves the items from each content type, and sorts them correctly within their own group, but doesn't weave the two sets together, according to date.  This means that if I set the pager down to 5 items (the goal), then I'll only see tradeshows, since there are more than 5.

Is there a way to get Views to shuffle the two types together, and show the next 5 events, combined?

Edit: attaching screenshot
[image]

Comment: can you give us a screen shot of your Views UI and how you are sorting?  From comments below, it appears that you don't have a common field on which to sort, and if that's the case, well, then that's the issue right there: Views is sorting on one field and then sorting on the other, and things are getting aggregated accordingly. Thus, you might need to put another hidden field in the nodes that is populated from whichever field is there and then sort on that field.

Comment: I guess Views is doing its sort on the first content type before retrieving the second set. If it pulled all the data and then sorted, it should use whichever of the two fields is present. I think you might have hit on the solution, though. I've already been using Views:Conditional to populate a field with the type selected. I could make another one for the date field, and use that to sort. I'll try it and report back. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: No joy. Views won't allow you to pick a Views:Conditional field for sorting. It has to be a field from the content type.  :(

Comment: You can turn on the sql preview to see what exactly Views is doing, but since there is no common field between the content types, it doesn't know how to aggregate this seemingly totally different fields.  So, unless you create a common date field between these node types, this is what you are going to get.  You can create one as I mentioned in my first comment and have it populated (via hook_node_presave()) from whichever of these fields is in fact present in the node and then sort on this new field.

Comment: I'm afraid you've lost me there.  I'm learning, but that's still beyond my ken!

Comment: Would that function go into a module, or the mysterious preprocess functions that I don't have a handle on yet? Can you point me at some learning material?

Comment: all of this goes in a module: the preprocess functions and any and all other hooks and so forth.

Comment: Okay, I can write a module. However, I'm still looking to expand my (very limited) knowledge of how the system as a whole works together. Is there no way to accomplish this solely using a template.php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, using hook_views_query_alter() turned out to be the simplest solution for my needs. I used code similar to that found in the solution below.

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/53128/18497

Answer (score 0):

Use Same field to pick date for Tradeshows as well as Webinars using existing field in content type. After that sort view accroding to that date field.

Comment: The date fields are not the same between the two content types.  Webinars have a combined date/time field, and Tradeshows have a combined start/end date.